# Override toString to remove spaces between elements

Tags: java, overriding, tostring, space

As you know, the toString() method called on a Vector output this

```
[foo, bar, item, item4]
```

This is pretty basic but, how could I get this instead (removing white spaces between elements)?

```
[foo,bar,item,item4]
```

Thank you all

EDIT: return nom.toString().replace(" ", "");  is not a solution !

Comment: Do you want to remove **ALL** spaces or only the space between elements?  That is, what would be your desired output for `[John Smith, Jane Doe, Will Williams]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your vector class and override toString.

```
import java.util.*;
class AwesomeVector<E> extends Vector<E> {

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
           if(i != 0) sb.append(","); 
           sb.append(get(i));
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AwesomeVector<String> av = new AwesomeVector<String>();
        av.add("This");
        av.add("is");
        av.add("a test");
        System.out.println(av.toString());
    }

}


C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>javac AwesomeVector.java

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java AwesomeVector
[This,is,a test]
```

Answer (score 3):

Overriding only makes sense if you are subclassing `Vector`.

If you are, then you can use Apache Commons Lang's [StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20char%29) as follows:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[" + StringUtils.join(this, ",") + "]";
}
```

If you want to stay in plain Java, glowcoder has the best answer.

Comment: I like the idea of leveraging Apache Commons to do things for you, just as a general rule it's nice.

Answer (score 2):

Just extend Vector class and override the `toString()`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer sb = new Stringbuffer("[");

    for(int i=0; i < elementCount ;i++ ){
         sb.append(elementData.toString());
         if(i!= elementCount -1){
             sb.append(",");
         }
    } 

    sb.append("]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: return nom.toString().replace(" ", "");  works well, but what if one of my element is "I am a space"... I know that I have to override it, but I can't manage to get it right.

Comment: provided the better implementation

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that you don't have `", "` in your elements, you can try:

```
System.out.println(v.toString().replace(", ", ","));
```